# programmatically create downloadable product showing out of stock

Tags: php, magento, magento-1.7

I have created downloadable product in magento 1.7. it created successfully but it showing `Availability: Out of stock` on product view page. I have to save product from admin panel to make it available

my code is as below

```
Mage::getSingleton("core/session", array("name" => "frontend"));

    $storeId = Mage::app()->getStore()->getId(); // get store id

    $filePath = Mage::getBaseUrl(Mage_Core_Model_Store::URL_TYPE_MEDIA);

    try {
        $product = Mage::getModel('catalog/product');
        $product->setStoreId($storeId);
        $product->setWebsiteIds(array(
                Mage::app()->getStore($storeId)->getWebsiteId()));
        $product->setAttributeSetId(4);
        $product->setHasOptions(4);
        $product->setTypeId('downloadable');
        $product->setSku(date('YmdHis'));
        $product->setPrice('1.23');
        $product->setStatus(1);
        $product->setVisibility(4);
        $product->setTaxClassId(0);
        $product->setStockData(array('is_in_stock'=>0, 'qty' => 1));
        $product->setLinksPurchasedSeparately(0);
        $product->setEnableGooglecheckout(0);
        $product->setIsImported(0);
        $product->setLinksExist(false);
        $product->setDescription($desc);
        $product->setShortDescription($desc); //added, meta description to 'short description' field, you can change this value
        $product->setMetaKeyword($desc);
        $product->setCustomLayoutUpdate(NULL);
        $product->setName($album_name."-".date('ymdis'));
        $product->setMetaTitle($desc);
        $product->setMetaDescription($desc);
        $product->setLinksTitle("Download");

        $product->setStockData(array(
                'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 
                'qty' => 1, 
                'min_qty' => 0, 
                'use_config_min_qty' => 0, 
                'min_sale_qty' => 0, 
                'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 0, 
                'max_sale_qty' => 0, 
                'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1, 
                'is_qty_decimal' => 0, 
                'backorders' => 0, 
                'notify_stock_qty' => 0, 
                'is_in_stock' => 1
        ));



        $linkfile = array();
        $samplefile = array();
        $_highfilePath = "/highresolution/".$album_name."/" . $fname;
        $_samplefilePath = "/lowresolution/".$album_name."/" . $fname;

        $paths = array('highurl' => $_highfilePath, 'sampleurl' => $_samplefilePath);
        $samplefile[] = array(
                'file' => $_samplefilePath,
                'name' => $fname,
                'size' => $files['size'][0],
                'status' => 'new'
        );

        $linkfile[] = array(
                'file' => $_highfilePath,
                'name' => $fname,
                'size' => $files['size'][0],
                'status' => 'new'
        );

        $tmpBasePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'highresolution' . DS . $album_name;
        $tmpSampleBasePath = Mage::getBaseDir('media') . DS . 'lowresolution' . DS . $album_name;

        $BashPathUrl = $filePath.'highresolution/'.$album_name.'/'.$fname;
        $SamplePathUrl = $filePath.'lowresolution/'.$album_name.'/'.$fname;

        $product->addImageToMediaGallery($tmpSampleBasePath. DS. $fname, array ('image','small_image','thumbnail'), false, false);
        $product->save();

        $linkFileName = Mage::helper('downloadable/file')->moveFileFromTmp(
                Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::getBaseTmpPath(),
                Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::getBasePath(),
                $linkfile
        );

        $linkModel = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')->setData(array(
                'product_id' => $product->getId(),
                'sort_order' => 0,
                'number_of_downloads' => 0, // Unlimited downloads
                'is_shareable' => 2, // Not shareable
                'link_url' => '',
                'link_type' => 'file',
                'link_file' => json_encode($linkfile),
                'sample_url' => $SamplePathUrl,
                'sample_file' => json_encode($samplefile),
                'sample_type' => 'url',
                'use_default_title' => false,
                'title' => 'downloadable link',
                'default_price' => 0,
                'price' => 0,
                'store_id' => 0,
                'website_id' => $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),
        ));

        $linkModel->setLinkFile($linkFileName)->save();
        return $product->getProductUrl();
    } catch (Exception $e) {
        echo "Exception : ".$e->getMessage();
        exit;
    }
```

Comment: Hi pragnesh please help me in adding the link to downloadable product programmatically, so far i am able to create downloadable product using your above code, but when i try to add links to products it gives me error 'error while saving file.'

Comment: @DepH, can you show your code or post your question that will more helpfull.

Comment: follow this link to question http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18574848/downloadable-product-add-file-links-to-downloadable-product-programmatically

Comment: try $product->setStockData(array('is_in_stock'=>1, 'qty' => 1)); and check

Comment: @ravisoni, have you tried from this link? http://www.deepcodeonline.com/#!/blog/magento/how-to-set-inventory-stock-quantity-outside-magento-non-web-service-method/

Comment: Yes I've checked and fixed it .. but the link sample is not adding to product.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

i have changed this and it is working

First remove this code

```
$product->setStockData(array(
            'use_config_manage_stock' => 1, 
            'qty' => 1, 
            'min_qty' => 0, 
            'use_config_min_qty' => 0, 
            'min_sale_qty' => 0, 
            'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 0, 
            'max_sale_qty' => 0, 
            'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1, 
            'is_qty_decimal' => 0, 
            'backorders' => 0, 
            'notify_stock_qty' => 0, 
            'is_in_stock' => 1
    ));
```

then add below code

```
$product->save();
$stockItem = Mage::getModel('cataloginventory/stock_item')->loadByProduct($product->getId());
$stockItemId = $stockItem->getId();
$stock = array();
if (!$stockItemId) {
    $stockItem->setData('product_id', $product->getId());
    $stockItem->setData('stock_id', 1);
} else {
        $stock = $stockItem->getData();
}
$stockItem->setIsInStock(1);
$stockItem->save();
```

Comment: from this link http://www.deepcodeonline.com/blog/magento/how-to-set-inventory-stock-quantity-outside-magento-non-web-service-method/

Answer (score 1):

In your code the:

```
'min_qty' => 1,
```

means the setting "Qty for Item's Status to Become Out of Stock", so if this has the same value as "qty", it will show "out of stock". Increase Qty or decrease this value to 0.

Comment: also tried `'min_qty' => 1, 'qty => 0'` still not working
also this  
`$stockData = $product->getStockData();
$stockData['qty'] = 10;
$stockData['is_in_stock'] = 1;
$stockData['manage_stock'] = 1;
$stockData['use_config_manage_stock'] = 0;
$product->setStockData($stockData);`

Comment: try to change only 'min_qty'=> 0 in the code above. This should work.

Comment: are your indexes in "manual" mode, or "update on save"? (System/Index management)

Comment: strange, if i execute your code with the stock-settings like:
`'use_config_manage_stock' => 1,
                'qty' => 1,
                'min_qty' => 0,
                'use_config_min_qty' => 0,
                'min_sale_qty' => 0,
                'use_config_min_sale_qty' => 0,
                'max_sale_qty' => 0,
                'use_config_max_sale_qty' => 1,
                'is_qty_decimal' => 0,
                'backorders' => 0,
                'notify_stock_qty' => 0,
         'is_in_stock' => 1`
It works for me, Availability: in stock

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/24175/discussion-between-pragnesh-chauhan-and-peter-gulyas)

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked the backend setting for Qty for Items' Status to Become Out of Stock: if that is set to more than 1 then your item will show Out of stock. Just another thing you can check

Cheers