# Downloadable product : add file links to downloadable product programmatically

Tags: magento

I am trying to add link to downloadable product programmatically, below is the code on which i am working.

```
$linkfile = array();
$_highfilePath = $FolderPath.DS.$fname;
$linkfile[] = array(
        'file' => $filePath,
        'name' => $fname,
        'size' => filesize($filePath),
        'status' => 'new'
);

$linkFileName = Mage::helper('downloadable/file')->moveFileFromTmp(
            Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::getBaseTmpPath(),
            Mage_Downloadable_Model_Link::getBasePath(),
            $linkfile
    );

    $linkModel = Mage::getModel('downloadable/link')->setData(array(
            'product_id' => $product->getId(),
            'sort_order' => 0,
            'number_of_downloads' => 0, // Unlimited downloads
            'is_shareable' => 2, // Not shareable
            'link_url' => '',
            'link_type' => 'file',
            'link_file' => json_encode($linkfile),
            'sample_url' => $SamplePathUrl,
            'sample_file' => json_encode($linkfile),
            'sample_type' => 'file',
            'use_default_title' => true,
            'default_price' => 0,
            'price' => 0,
            'store_id' => 0,
            'website_id' => $product->getStore()->getWebsiteId(),
    ));
```

and this is the error i get `An error occurred while saving the file(s).`.
Please help

Answer (score 0):

Impossible to diagnose with certainty without more information.  Here's the code for the call that's failing:

```
/**
 * Checking file for moving and move it
 *
 * @param string $baseTmpPath
 * @param string $basePath
 * @param array $file
 * @return string
 */
public function moveFileFromTmp($baseTmpPath, $basePath, $file)
{
    if (isset($file[0])) {
        $fileName = $file[0]['file'];
        if ($file[0]['status'] == 'new') {
            try {
                $fileName = $this->_moveFileFromTmp(
                    $baseTmpPath, $basePath, $file[0]['file']
                );
            } catch (Exception $e) {
                Mage::throwException(Mage::helper('downloadable')->__('An error occurred while saving the file(s).'));
            }
        }
        return $fileName;
    }
    return '';
}
```

A good place to start would be checking filesystem permissions, making sure your datatypes match the types specified in the function comments, and making sure all files and directories exist.